# Get most recent ROW with a GROUP BY on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to get the most resent result for every amount linked to a duration.
This is my table :

```
 SELECT * FROM financement;

 id    amount   duration   total
 8       200     5       result8
 7       200     4       result7 
 6       100     5       result6
 5       100     4       result5 
 4       200     5       result4
 3       200     4       result3
 2       100     5       result2
 1       100     4       result1
```

There is is a total for every amount linked to a duration.
My problematic is that, they can be multiple row for the same amout x duration and I only want the most recent.
For exemple in my case :

```
id    amount   duration   total
5       100     4       result5 
1       100     4       result1
```

I tried to use a GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `financement` GROUP BY amout, duration ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

But with this method, even with the ORDER BY id DESC, I still get the most ancien ROW.
I also tried to SELECT max() in a sub query like this, but the query is extremely long and it times out.

```
SELECT * financement where id in (select max(id) from financement group by amount, duration);
```

How can I get this output ?

```
id    amount   duration   total
8       200     5       result8
7       200     4       result7 
6       100     5       result6
5       100     4       result5
```

Comment: _Most recent_, does that mean _highest id_?

Comment: Yes exactly @jarlh

Comment: Simply `select * from financement order by id desc limit 4`?

Comment: I have millions of Rows in my table financement, I don't want a solution with hardcoded limit

Comment: `I have millions of Rows in my table financement, I don't want a solution with hardcoded limit` I don't understand the implied sequitur of this statement

Comment: Do you have any indexes on this table, or have the option to index this table?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `financement` 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT max(id) as id FROM `financement` GROUP BY duration, amount
)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want filtering.  You can use a scalar subquery:

```
select f.*
from financement f
where f.id = (select max(f2.id)
              from financement f2
              where f2.amount = f.amount and f2.duration = f.duration
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

SELECT * FROM financement ORDER BY id DESC

[output of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxpdL.png)